# Finding Where Clause Criteria in SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table which has 3 different Select queries.

e.g.

```
              Staff
              ------------------------------------------------------------
              ID   Code   Name   Phone  DOB   Email   Addr1   Addr2  Addr3


    Query1
    Select ID, Code, Phone From Staff Where Code = 'ABC'

    Query2
    Select ID, Code, Phone From Staff Where Name = 'ABCXYZ' And Code = 'B'

    Query3
    Select ID, Code, Phone From Staff Where Phone= '1234' And Email = 'a@b'
```

These 3 queries are there in 3 different stored procedure.

I want to find the names of Attributes which i have used in all my Where clauses. But want to Automate this as I have more than 100 tables to look for

Something like this

```
             exec fxGetWhereColList ('Staff');
```

### Result:

```
                Code
                Name
                Phone
                Email
```

Comment: I would say that this is nearly impossible to do. You'll need to parse every `and`, `or`, `between` and other things just to know which columns are used. What if they are used in a function?, what if there are joins?, dynamic sql?, etc

Comment: You could script all of your stored procedures into one query window, then find all `Where` clauses. More manual, but all in one window.

Comment: Needs work but you could search the body of your procs for WHERE.
You could then usee CHARINDEX to get the following N number of characters.
Needs work but here is a start for this odyssey;)

SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc,
       m.definition,
       REPLACE(m.definition,' ', '')
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE 
 REPLACE(m.definition,' ', '') Like '%WHERE%'

Comment: Do the queries in the procedures use passed parameters? If so, use a naming convention so that the parameter variables are always the same as the columns they intend to search. It is then easy to grab the attributes straight from the parameter list.

Comment: Hi cloudsafe, thank you for the comment. Is it possible to get the Parameter list for any Stored procedure using a TSQL or it will also be a manual process?

Answer (score 0):

Like Lamak says, doing this right is nearly impossible, at least in SQL.

To do it properly you should use a SQL Parser for the SQL variant you are using. A SQL Parser will identify the objects referenced in the statement, and the elements of the where clauses.

But if you know that the queries are simple and look like the one you are listing, you can use some simple queries to pick apart the statements. I have made an example for a single statement:

```
declare 
    @foo nvarchar(max)=N'Select ID, Code, Phone From Staff Where Phone= ''1234'' And Email = ''a@b''     '
    , @From nvarchar(max)=' From '
    , @Table nvarchar(max)
declare @a int

-- find FROM
set @a= PATINDEX('%'+@From+'%',@foo) 
-- Find statement to the right of from
set @foo=ltrim(RIGHT(@foo,len(@foo)-(@a))) 
-- Find first space
set @a=CHARINDEX(' ',@foo) 
-- find first word, we assume it is the table name
set @Table=ltrim(rtrim(LEFT(@foo,@a))) 
-- Find WHERE statement
set @foo=ltrim(rtrim(replace(right(@foo,len(@foo)-@a),'Where','')))

-- Now find matching columns in table, I am using SQL Server so I look up column names in information_schema.columns
select @Table,column_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
--from (values ('ID'),('Code'),('Name'),('Phone'),('DOB'),('Email'),('Addr1'),('Addr2'),('Addr3'))cols(column_name) 
where TABLE_NAME=@table
and @foo like '%'+column_name+'%'
```

This solution will only work for some simple statements, it assumes a lot of stuff.

Comment: Thanks Soren. As you rightly guessed, the queries are bit more complicated. I had posted a simpler query in order to make myself clear. I was looking for some sql option to get the list, as i assumed sql server must be knowing it while executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all posts before, it's a complex case.

I post you a small idea to help you in your work.
If you can retrieve each execution plan, you can parse XML result and get the impacted columns.

For example: On the node <Predicate>

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Thanks Arnuad. Is it possible to get all query plans of queries from one particular table?